# Sleep shortcut command lubuntu?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, lubuntu, sleep, xscreensaver

I'm trying to set the *Sleep Button* to actually put the computer to sleep and toggle my screensaver but to make this happen I have to have a terminal command to bind to the sleep button. So by going to  **Preferences -> Setup Hot Keys -> Programs**  and then assing a command to the sleep key.

I tried using the command `xscreensaver-command -lock ; lxsession-logout --suspend` but when I press the sleep button nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? My Lubuntu version is 17.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your xscreensaver is running? You can check the existence of the process with `ps -aux | grep -v ps | grep xscreensaver`. If xscreensaver is not running, you should run `xscreensaver --no-splash & disown` and you would want to put this command in your .xinitrc or whatever lightdm uses for on login configurations.

If you already have xscreensaver running but the bind does not work, then maybe you are not binding the key correctly. Try following a solution similar to the one in [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276975/is-it-possible-to-key-bind-the-pasting-of-the-x-clipboard-how) and replace the `Command` field with `xscreensaver-command -lock`.

It is also possible that `lxsession-logout` is doing something weird to xscreensaver (I don't know, never used lxsession-logout with xscreensaver), but nonetheless you should execute `lxsession-logout --suspend` before the `xscreensaver-command -lock` since `lxsession-logout` prompts for a logout screen and `xscreensaver-command -lock` locks your screen immediately (depending on the fade duration).

Comment: xscreensaver does seem to be working. Following the other guide and replacing the `Command` field with `xscreensaver-command -lock` didn't work either so I tried the `lxsession-logout --suspend ; xscreensaver-command -lock` and that didn't seem to work either. So i dug around and `lxsession-logout --suspend` does absolutely nothing! So I tried `lxsession-logout` and that did work, bringing up the logout, shutdown, and suspend options. So `lxsession-logout --suspend` seems to be what's not working. So what do I do now?

Comment: Why doesn't your keybind just run `xscreensaver-command -lock`? I think that is enough.

Comment: I'm not sure why `xscreensaver-command -lock` isn't working. Is there any way to check why it's not working?

Comment: Try `xscreensaver-demo`. Use the lock demo on the graphical interface and check if you can lock it. You can also check the logs or just run xscreensaver without daemonizing it using only `xscreensaver` and when you try to lock check if it spits any error. You can also turn on verbose with the flag `-verbose`.

Comment: Ok, so after running `xscreensaver-demo` it told me I had to daemonize it before I could use it. After I did that `xscreensaver-command -lock` started working! Thanks so much! :D